Do you need supplementary car insurance driving a EU-insured car in Jersey?
I am thinking about bringing my EU registered car for a day-trip in Jersey, Channel Islands.
My Green Card has coverage for the UK, does that apply to the Channel Islands as well?

If you green card has the "GB" symbol, it is valid also in Jersey (but not time for official documentation, so am answer)

Information on the JerseySafeRoads website states:

Visiting motorists are required to be in possession of a current driving licence (not provisional) and insurance certificate.

The Jersey government’s Travel and Transport page (which I think is aimed at expats but seems applicable to visitors too), says:

When driving in Jersey, you’ll need to have the following documents on you when you’re driving (photocopies are not acceptable):



a certificate of insurance or an International Green Card
a valid driving licence or International Driving Permit (IDP).


If you want to double-check, you can contact the relevant Green Card Bureau.
Jersey is a very small island that gets very crowded in summer. Parking may not be easy to find, and on public car parks you may need to pay by an app
